# Generating Duplicate Data Series

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This example I am trying to generate and add column 1 to 5 as many number as I want. Can I solve with "Connect By" function or another function?

```
SELECT level
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <=5;

  ID   Name   Expected Outcome
-----   ----  ---------------
  1     | A  |  1
  2     | B  |  2
  3     | C  |  3
  4     | D  |  4
  5     | E  |  5
  6     | F  |  1
  7     | G  |  2
  8     | G  |  3
  9     | A  |  4
  10    | E  |  5
  11    | E  |  1
  12    | E  |  2
```

Comment: Your edit has modified your request a lot. Before it seemed you wanted to generate rows with those numbers. And indeed you create rows with `CONNECT BY` (or a recursive CTE). Now you want to select rows from a table instead and add the numbers there. So, you are no longer generating rows. Anyway, as you want to count until 5 and then start over, you'll use the `MOD` function as show in Koen Lostrie's answer in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `MOD` function:

```
SELECT MOD(level - 1,5) + 1 
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <=20;

1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Well... if you want to write a function yourself that behaves like MOD, go ahead. It works.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what that means. Can you update your question with this information, explaining clearly what you are starting with and what the expected result is ?

Comment: @Motif: So it is a table you want to select from. It is still `MOD` you'll want. Only that you'll invoke it on the row number of your table's rows ordered by ID instead: `mod(row_number() over(order by id) - 1, 5) + 1`.